# cordova plugin.xml framework replaces my build.gradle

Tags: cordova, build.gradle, cordova-plugins, plugin.xml, plugman

I write as below

```
<framework src="platforms/android/IMKit" custom="true" />
```

But my build.gradle file under platforms/android/IMKit is replaced by cordova with its own one. How to avoid cordova replacing my build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed build.gradle to build-extras.gradle, then it is ok.

Comment: how i write in build-extras.gradle,android packageoptions exclude metainf-license please help